# Java - "Text 'Oct 11' could not be parsed at index 0"

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a simple `DateTime` with a different format. This line is just gibing me a hard time:

```
LocalDate.parse("Oct 11, 2021", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy"))
```

This is something trivial, why is it not working if I am providing the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception indicates your system language is not English<sup>1</sup> (so `Oct` isn't a month name in the default locale). Specify the locale. Like,

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("Oct 11, 2021",
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US));
System.out.println(ld);
```

Outputs

```
2021-10-11
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>Your original code worked for me, because my locale is English.</sub>